# Error Starting Standalone Cache Service

Tags: web8, cache-channel-service

I get the following error when trying to start the Cache Channel Windows service

> The SDLWebCacheService service terminated with the following
>   service-specific error:  The system cannot open the file.

The service creates no other logs.

When I start the service as a process (using `Start.ps1`) it runs without any issue and creates log files.

When started as a windows service it fails to start

Comment: Can you check on the path the windows service is installed on? could be a permission issue that the file is not executable

Comment: Do you happen to have a space in the path to the services? We seem to have found a similar issue that is only reproduced when there is a space in the path...

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of problem, the first tool you reach for should be [Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) `procmon`. This will enable you to see exactly which file can't be opened, and also to get other information, such as which process was involved, what kind of access was specified for the file open, and what account it was using. Usually this is sufficient to solve problems like this.

When you run `Start.ps1`, what credentials are you using? Are they the same as the credentials that the service uses?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug with the installer with the installation path contains blank spaces. As a temporary fix remove all the blank spaces

Answer (score 1):

To get more details around the issue, try running the service as a console application with debug log mode:

.\procrun.exe //TS//SDLWebCacheService --LogLevel Debug

Answer (score 1):

Use Regedit and check the following name:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\SDLWebCacheService\Parameters\Java

If there are spaces in the name of the service, you will find that the Classpath is truncated at the first space. (Instead it should look more like this, although the other services use a dot to reference the current directory.)

> C:\SDLWebCDServices\Cache\bin..\lib*;C:\SDLWebCDServices\Cache\bin..\config

I'm not sure I'd recommend fixing this in the registry. It's probably better just to rename the folder without spaces and install the service again.