# Discovery service startup error: "The system cannot open the file."

Tags: web8.5, installation, microservices

When I start my SDL Web 8.5 discovery micro service (fresh install) as a Windows service it cannot start. I found this error in the event viewer:

```
The SDL Web Discovery Service service terminated with the following 
service-specific error: 
The system cannot open the file.
```

The service does not write anything to the log file either, it does not even create the log file. (the one specified in logback.xml).

Any idea what this is about?

The Windows service points to `C:\SDLWeb\staging\discovery\bin\procrun.exe //RS//SDLWebDiscoveryService` This path does exist.

Answer (score 1):

have you seen this post? Although for CCS, maybe it helps nonetheless:
[Error Starting Standalone Cache Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/error-starting-standalone-cache-service)

Just looking at the path above, I don't see it, but just in case double-check for spaces in path (or slashes).

Try running with procrun (debug mode) - see sample for CCS in post above.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your discovery service is trying to start the procrun.exe located in C:\SDLWeb\staging\discovery\bin. Make sure it exists there

//RS//SDLWebDiscoveryService is an option to the startup script.

Even when all of the above are correct, I have seen some similar behavior due to missing jar dependencies/tags added to ambient_data_Conf, but missing jars. In some of those cases, there won't be any log messages created, could be something similar at your end.